# ColdFusion/Java strange script

Tags: java, coldfusion

Just found this weird script on the server of one of my clients. I'm not a CFML pro. Can somebody tell me if is a genuine ColdFusion script or a hacker shell and if so what it does? The name was `cf_fun.cfm`

```xml
<cfset sf = CreateObject("java", "coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory")>
<cfset rxml="">

<cftry>
  <cfscript>
   rxml = XmlNew();
   rxml.xmlRoot = XmlElemNew(rxml,"result");
   rxml.result.XmlText = "0";
  </cfscript>

  <cfswitch expression="#Trim(exec_mode)#"> 
   <cfcase value="encode"> 
    <cfscript>
     sres = sf.DataSourceService.encryptPassword(param);
     rxml.result.XmlChildren[1] = XmlElemNew(rxml,"param");
     rxml.result.param.XmlText = param;
     rxml.result.XmlChildren[2] = XmlElemNew(rxml,"encoded");
     rxml.result.encoded.XmlText = sres;
    </cfscript>
   </cfcase> 

   <cfcase value="test"> 
    <cfscript>
      sf.DataSourceService.verifyDatasource(param);
    </cfscript>
   </cfcase> 

   <cfcase value="commit"> 
    <cfscript>
      sf.DataSourceService.load();
    </cfscript>
   </cfcase> 

   <cfcase value="rollback"> 
    <cfscript>
      sf.DataSourceService.store();
    </cfscript>
   </cfcase> 

   <cfdefaultcase> 
    <cfthrow message="Invalid command specified" errorCode = "1" >
   </cfdefaultcase> 
  </cfswitch> 
<cfcatch>
    <cfscript>
     rxml = XmlNew();
     rxml.xmlRoot = XmlElemNew(rxml,"result");
     rxml.result.XmlText = "-1";
     rxml.result.XmlChildren[1] = XmlElemNew(rxml,"description");
     rxml.result.description.XmlText = cfcatch.message;
    </cfscript>
</cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfoutput>#rxml#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: looks genuine to me, but I am not familiar with the ServiceFactory object so I don't really know what the code does.

Comment: As an aside, that is a terrible naming choice. My first thought would be malicious script too ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not tell us what version of ColdFusion you are running or where you found that file?  I have never heard of it before.  I searched my ColdFusion 9.0.1 server and could not find it anywhere.  I also searched Google and found a specific reference to a file with that name [here](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?113196-Plesk-CF-DSN-XML-Error).  Which makes it seem as though that file is part of Plesk Panel. The reference that I found is listed under [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) which is a hosting company.  Are you using them for hosting or are you using the Plesk Panel?  If so, then it appears to be a legitimate file.

I found [another post here](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?71505-Coldfusion-on-Plesk) where a Parallel's team member replied that "Plesk does not support ColdFusion DSN and Sandbox". Since the code you shared appears to be related to ColdFusion datasources perhaps it is their "hook" into creating/editing DSNs for ColdFusion using their panel.

Just my guess...

Comment: Found it on a ColdFusion 9, and yes, the server has Plesk installed also.

Comment: I can also verify that this is plesk.  I came across it too back in January when all the coldfusion security updates affecting the administrator came out.  I thought it may have been part of a hack attempt, but it was part of plesk.